# Can't get desired results using try/except clause within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in `scrapy` to make proxied requests using newly generated proxies by `get_proxies()` method. I used `requests` module to fetch the proxies in order to reuse them in the script. What I'm trying to do is parse all the movie links from it's [landing page](https://yts.am/browse-movies) and then fetch the name of each movie from it's [target page](https://yts.am/movie/jasper-jones-2017). My following script can use rotation of proxies.

I know there is an easier way to change proxies, like it is described here [HttpProxyMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=process_exception#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy) but I would still like to stick to the way I'm trying here.

[website link](https://yts.am/browse-movies)

This is my current attempt (It keeps using new proxies to fetch a valid response but every time it gets `503 Service Unavailable`):

```
import scrapy
import random
import requests
from itertools import cycle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

def get_proxies():   
    response = requests.get("https://www.us-proxy.org/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    proxy = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text,item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in soup.select("table.table tbody tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    return proxy

class ProxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "proxiedscript"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [503]
    proxy_vault = get_proxies()
    check_url = "https://yts.am/browse-movies"

    def start_requests(self):
        random.shuffle(self.proxy_vault)
        proxy_url = next(cycle(self.proxy_vault))
        request = scrapy.Request(self.check_url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
        request.meta['https_proxy'] = f'http://{proxy_url}'
        yield request

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.meta)
        if "DDoS protection by Cloudflare" in response.css(".attribution > a::text").get():
            random.shuffle(self.proxy_vault)
            proxy_url = next(cycle(self.proxy_vault))
            request = scrapy.Request(self.check_url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
            request.meta['https_proxy'] = f'http://{proxy_url}'
            yield request

        else:
            for item in response.css(".browse-movie-wrap a.browse-movie-title::attr(href)").getall():
                nlink = response.urljoin(item)
                yield scrapy.Request(nlink,callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self,response):
        name = response.css("#movie-info h1::text").get()
        yield {"Name":name}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c.crawl(ProxySpider)
    c.start()
```

To make sure whether the request is being proxied, I printed `response.meta` and could get results like this `{'https_proxy': 'http://142.93.127.126:3128', 'download_timeout': 180.0, 'download_slot': 'yts.am', 'download_latency': 0.237013578414917, 'retry_times': 2, 'depth': 0}`.

As I've overused the link to check how the proxied request within scrapy works, I'm getting `503 Service Unavailable` error at this moment and I can see this keyword within the response `DDoS protection by Cloudflare`. However, I get valid response when I try with `requests` module applying the same logic I implemented here.

`My earlier question: why I can't get the valid response as (I suppose) I'm using proxies in the right way? [solved]`

> ***Bounty Question: how can I define `try/except` clause within my script so that it will try with different proxies once it throws connection error with a certain proxy?***

Comment: Can you post the headers you get when you use the requests module instead of scrapy?

Comment: Sure. Here it is `requests.get(itemlink,proxies=proxy,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})` @Edeki Okoh.

Comment: The actual response from the header not the code itself. To see what format the proxies are being sent as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware` [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=proxymiddleware#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware)
(and [source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py#L48-L50))
`proxy` meta key is expected to use (not `https_proxy`)

```
#request.meta['https_proxy'] = f'http://{proxy_url}'  
request.meta['proxy'] = f'http://{proxy_url}'
```

As scrapy didn't received valid meta key - your scrapy application didn't use proxies

Answer (score 4):

The `start_requests()` function is just the entry point. On subsequent requests, you would need to resupply this metadata to the `Request` object.

Also, errors can occur on two levels: proxy and target server

We need to handle bad response codes from both the proxy and the target server. Proxy errors are returned by the middelware to the `errback` function. The target server response can be handled during parsing from the `response.status`

```py
import scrapy
import random
import requests
from itertools import cycle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


def get_proxies():
    response = requests.get("https://www.us-proxy.org/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    proxy = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text, item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in
             soup.select("table.table tbody tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    # proxy = ['https://52.0.0.1:8090', 'https://52.0.0.2:8090']
    return proxy


def get_random_proxy(proxy_vault):
    random.shuffle(proxy_vault)
    proxy_url = next(cycle(proxy_vault))
    return proxy_url


class ProxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "proxiedscript"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [503, 502, 401, 403]
    check_url = "https://yts.am/browse-movies"
    proxy_vault = get_proxies()

    def handle_middleware_errors(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # implement middleware error handling here
        print('Middleware Error')
        # retry request with different proxy
        yield self.make_request(url=args[0].request._url, callback=args[0].request._meta['callback'])

    def start_requests(self):
        yield self.make_request(url=self.check_url, callback=self.parse)

    def make_request(self, url, callback, dont_filter=True):
        return scrapy.Request(url,
                              meta={'proxy': f'https://{get_random_proxy(self.proxy_vault)}', 'callback': callback},
                              callback=callback,
                              dont_filter=dont_filter,
                              errback=self.handle_middleware_errors)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.meta)
        try:
            if response.status != 200:
                # implement server status code handling here - this loops forever
                print(f'Status code: {response.status}')
                raise
            else:
                for item in response.css(".browse-movie-wrap a.browse-movie-title::attr(href)").getall():
                    nlink = response.urljoin(item)
                    yield self.make_request(url=nlink, callback=self.parse_details)
        except:
            # if anything goes wrong fetching the lister page, try again
            yield self.make_request(url=self.check_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        print(response.meta)
        try:
            if response.status != 200:
                # implement server status code handeling here - this loops forever
                print(f'Status code: {response.status}')
                raise
            name = response.css("#movie-info h1::text").get()
            yield {"Name": name}
        except:
            # if anything goes wrong fetching the detail page, try again
            yield self.make_request(url=response.request._url, callback=self.parse_details)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c.crawl(ProxySpider)
    c.start()
```

Comment: Also an improvement to this would be is to create a list of working proxies while crawling and use these over a random one.

Comment: When an error in the middleware occurs, the function ```handle_middleware_errors``` is called. This is, from what I could see, always called with a list of errors. From the tests I have done, I could see the error is always on index 0 ```args[0]```. The error also contains the original ```request```, and the original request always has ```_url``` and a ```_meta['callback']``` (since we explicitly set the callback on each request to be part of the meta dict). This allows to retry ```make_request()``` again with the original parameters.

Comment: Could you help me understand why `args[0].request._url` and `args[0].request.url` within ***`handle_middleware_errors()`*** are working in the same way even when there is no underscore ***`_`*** in the latter one. Thanks.

Comment: I might have missed the fact that they had a public attribute available. I would assume they are always the same within the scope of that function, in that case from a coding perspective, take the public attribute ```request.url```. Underscored functions and attributes in python are commonly used to communicate the function or attribute is ```private``` rather than ```public```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671487/what-is-the-difference-in-python-attributes-with-underscore-in-front-and-back

Comment: Would you care to give an idea why you used `callback` twice within `make_requests()` method @tvgriek ? Thanks.